# Inno Setup: How to run an installed batch file programmatically

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to run a `bat` file in the `Code` section (procedure `DeinitializeSetup`)?

As I tried to do:

```pascal
Exec('"' + installationFolder + '\mysql\db\db.cmd"',
     '"'+ installationFolder +'"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Source and destination parameters are returning to the correct locations.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with [these](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) commands, perhaps you'll have better luck. Otherwise, please include a more specific requirement to run, and/or what attempts you have made?

Comment: I need to run bat file in DeinitializeSetup to reconfigure and reinstall the Tomcat, Red5 and mySQL as service. These bat files will run if an error occurs or if the user cancels the installation, so the previous program is restored.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Source and destination parameters"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute the batch file, use [`Exec` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).

There should be no quotes in the `Filename` parameter of the `Exec()`.

```pascal
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var
  InstallationFolder: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  InstallationFolder := ExpandConstant('{app}');
  if Exec(InstallationFolder + '\mysql\db\test.bat',
          '"' + InstallationFolder + '"',
          '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    Log('Succeeded running batch file');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Failed running batch file');
  end;
end;
```

---

If I install a `test.bat` with this contents:

```
@echo off
echo This is test
echo The provided installation path is %1
echo Without quotes: %~1
echo The current working directory is:
cd
pause
```

using:

```
[Files]
Source: "test.bat"; DestDir: "{app}\mysql\db"
```

I get this at the end of the installation:

[image: Batch output]